# How to access Motion Paths found under Object properties through the script?

Tags: python, objects, path

I have a cube for which I have defined key frames in the range 0-100
How can I activate the Motion Paths found under Object properties through the script? I can't do it.

The ultimate goal is to get the perfect parabolic trajectory as you can see in the picture.

- Note - I have to do it through a code and not independently (by clicking on Update path)
  Thank you very much everyone

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems your ultimate goal can be achieved with two drivers:

First a simple driver to move the object along $x$ axis (though this could easily be achieved by 2 keyframes and a linear interpolation):

[image]

Then another driver to set the $z$ location to the sine of the current time (frame):

[image]

Keep in mind you could make it the sine of the current $x$ location instead: just right-click on the $x$ location, "Copy as a New Driver", right click on the $z$ location, "Paste Driver", right-click again, "Edit Driver", change to a scripted expression, and set to `sin(var)`.